# How to print the exact value of the field in cakephp3 with 3 tables joining

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Below are my 3 tables consist of users, websites and projects please see picture below for my desired output

241 is ID of the current login user.

users table fields

```
id
email
username
password
```

websites table fields

```
id
domain
company
```

projects table fields

```
id
int user_id   // select option to get from user 
varchar domain    // select option to get from websites table
varchar designer  // select option to get from user 
varchar developer // select option to get from user 
int price
```

UsersTable.php

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);
    $this->table('users');
    $this->belongsTo('Users');
    $this->hasMany('Subjects');
    $this->hasMany('Websites');
    $this->hasMany('Projects');
    $this->displayField('username');  // called in project add.ctp
    $this->primaryKey('id'); 
}
```

UsersController.php

```
public function project($id = null)
{
    $users = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => [
            'Projects'
        ]
    ]);
    $this->set('users', $users);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);

}
```

when i click a button my projects

My Projects

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Designer</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Developer</td>
    <td>Domain</td>
</tr>
<?php 
    if(!empty($users->projects)) {
        foreach($users->projects as $project) {
?>
    <tr>                              
    <td> <?php echo $project->designer;?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $project->price;?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $project->developer;?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $project->domain;?> </td>
    </tr>
<?php
        }
    }
    else{
        echo"You dont have any projects yet";
    }
?>
</table>
```

241 is ID of the  current login user, developer and designer could be different if admin will assign other developer and other designer

1. it will print the data but not the the value instead and ID
2. I dont know how to print the company

Output of `pr($users)`:

```
App\Model\Entity\User Object
(
    [username] => pcsodaily
    [password] => $2y$10$u3W..vnZ3ygXH3BhFJ2U0ui7qI2bwRJcM85tVR.SPUlNXsTdM/GNa
    [id] => 241
    [email] => pcsodailyresult@gmail.com
    [profile_pic] => Resource id #256
    [destination] => E:\xampp-for-cakephp3\htdocs\sibonga\webroot\img\users\pcsodaily\20643696_1656261664406406_1426837475_n.jpg
    [created] => 2018-04-06
    [age] => 30
    [address] => Bato, Sibonga Cebu
    [gender] => Male
    [firstname] => pcso
    [lastname] => calderon
    [activation_key] => f6aff532-2632-4440-a144-6006ae1aa374
    [status] => 1
    [pass_key] => 
    [timeout] => 
    [websites] => Array
        (
        )

    [projects] => Array
        (
            [0] => App\Model\Entity\Project Object
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [finished_time] => 2018-04-30
                    [designer] => 241
                    [developer] => 241
                    [price] => 200
                    [status] => live
                    [user_id] => 241
                    [domain] => 9
                    [[new]] => 
                    [[accessible]] => Array
                        (
                            [*] => 1
                            [id] => 
                        )

                    [[dirty]] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [[original]] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [[virtual]] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [[errors]] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [[invalid]] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [[repository]] => Projects
                )

        )

    [[new]] => 
    [[accessible]] => Array
        (
            [*] => 1
            [id] => 
        )

    [[dirty]] => Array
        (
        )

    [[original]] => Array
        (
        )

    [[virtual]] => Array
        (
        )

    [[errors]] => Array
        (
        )

    [[invalid]] => Array
        (
        )

    [[repository]] => Users
)
```

Comment: What part of this isn't doing what you expect it to? There's a lot of code here, I think most of it is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: I want to print domain, company from websites table and designer, developer, price  from projects table

Comment: You've shown the form for adding data to the database; this is useful only if the problem lies in saving data. Is that the case? If so, then you should reword your question. If you have good data in the database and are having problems displaying it, then seeing the add form doesn't help. Your project function shows a commented-out dump of the `$users` variable, it would be very helpful to see the output from that. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details on how to give us information that will help solve the problem.

Comment: this is the relation I mean Projects table had a relation in users table because of the user_id and in the websites table  .    https://ibb.co/n6H5wc

Comment: So there is data in your database. There's still a whole lot missing from your question before we can help you.

Comment: yes,  the image above, is the data in the database that i want to print

Comment: You've answered part of what I asked. I'll repeat the rest. Your project function shows a commented-out dump of the $users variable, it would be very helpful to see the output from that. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details on how to give us information that will help solve the problem.

Comment: It will now print the data, I dont know how i just added user_id field in projects table, https://ibb.co/cwdizx  one thing I will ask how can i print the 241 and 1 the exact value 241 is the user and 1 is domain with id 1 and also the in Userstable initialize is that already correct in cakephp

Comment: UPDATED,,,  it will only display if only 1 registered user in users table and it will not display if 2 or more users registered..  @GregSchmidt

Comment: You keep adding information, but not in a useful way. This makes it very hard to help you. Have you read the How To link that I've given you? It doesn't seem that the `add` function or form have anything at all to do with your problem; why are they included here? Also, screen shots of text, especially screen shots with small font and 80% of the space wasted, are not helpful, you should copy-and-paste the helpful bits of text instead. Fix these things, and add in some output from `pr($users)` in cases where it works and where it doesn't, and maybe people (me or others) will be able to help.

Comment: I already change the question sir @GregSchmidt

Comment: Yet you still haven't included the output from a `pr($users)`. It's like you've asked how to get to where you're going, and I ask you where you're going, and your response is "I also need to stop at my mom's house on the way there".

Comment: pr($users->projects);die;     https://pastebin.com/a2mXT3Sg

Comment: pr($users);die;    https://pastebin.com/tYB6QFdq

Comment: Note, I edited your question a bit into something that could have been answered right away, without all this discussion, as an example of how to present the information you need to share to get good help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `designer` and `developer` fields in your `projects` table appear to be intended as IDs to reference records in the `users` table. Those should definitely be integers, not varchars, and if you aren't very far into this project yet, I'd suggest that you also change them to `designer_id` and `developer_id` instead. If you can do that, then your `ProjectsTable` should have an initialize function like this:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);
    $this->table('projects');
    $this->belongsTo('Designers', [
        'foreign_key' => 'designer_id',
        'className' => 'Users',
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Developers', [
        'foreign_key' => 'developer_id',
        'className' => 'Users',
    ]);
    $this->primaryKey('id'); 
}
```

Once this is done, your `project` function becomes more like this:

```
$users = $this->Users->get($id, [
    'contain' => [
        'Projects' => [
            'Designers',
            'Developers',
        ]
    ]
]);
```

and then your template can use

```
<?php echo $project->designer->username; ?>
<?php echo $project->developer->username; ?>
```

If for some reason you can't change the field names to add `_id` to the end, you will need to add the `propertyName` option in your `belongsTo` calls, to change the name of the property where you'll be able to access the related entities. For example, `'propertyName' => 'designer_record'`, and then your template would need to say

```
<?php echo $project->designer_record->username; ?>
```

instead.

You could also add

```
$this->hasMany('DesignedProjects', [
    'foreign_key' => 'designer_id',
    'className' => 'Projects',
]);
```

into your `UsersTable::initialize` function, and something similar for DevelopedProjects, if it's ever going to be useful to you to get a list of projects that the user designed or developed. You'd then be able to include `DesignedProjects` in your containment as required when reading users, and reference them with `$user->designed_projects`.

Side notes:

Pretty sure that users don't belong to users, contrary to your initialize function there.

It's much more standard to use `$user` as the variable name when you're getting a single entity than `$users`.

Comment: P.S. Also looks like `domain` in your projects table should maybe be `website_id`? Similar changes to what's described above would apply to this field.

Comment: It will now display the designer and developer name https://ibb.co/fiAHEx  but how to print the domain and company name.. I already change domain to website_id.

Comment: I thought  by adding below   /**Developers and Designers is a table *****/ $this->belongsTo('Developers', [
        'foreign_key' => 'developer_id',
        'className' => 'Users',
    ]);

Comment: why is it also if current user login is 241 , it will says no project and supposed he had 2 projects. i think data pulled out by user_id assign  https://ibb.co/fER2Ex

Comment: To print the domain, have you included a `belongsTo` for that table in `ProjectsTable::initialize`? You need to do all the same sorts of changes for this as you did for designer and developer. Read up more on [Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html) if it's still not clear to you how to connect various tables together.

Comment: To get projects that a user designed and developed, you need to read the section I wrote starting with "You could also add".

Comment: i added this already  $users = $this->Users->get($id, [
    'contain' => [
        'Projects' => [
            'Designers',
            'Developers',
            'Websites',
        ]
    ]
]);                                                                                                                            $this->belongsTo('Websites', [
        'foreign_key' => 'website_id',
               'className' => 'Users',
    ]);     then in view  <?php echo $project->website->domain;?>    Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Template\Users\project.ctp, line 26]

Comment: Did you read the Associations link I gave above? If you have read and understood that, you should know that the `className` here should be Websites, not Users. Users is appropriate in the `belongsTo` for Designers and Developers, because the designer and developer are user records, just under a different name. Seems there might be more wrong than just that one thing, though. I really think you need to read that link carefully and try to understand it. Right now, you're basically shooting in the dark hoping to randomly find a combination that works.

Comment: Some hints for how to debug your particular latest problem on your own. 1. Look at what is on line 26 of project.ctp. That's going to give you a very clear idea of what you are trying to reference. 2. pr($users) again, and learn how to read the output from that, so that you can go through it and find what is missing that line 26 is looking for. 3. Only then, if you still can't resolve it on your own, come back here and tell us *details* about what is missing. Maybe start a new question for that, as this one is getting further and further from the original point the longer it drags on.

Comment: I already had the correct output domain and company but , still dont know how to use you said.. on to print the users even not login  I already give you 35 votes :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168522/discussion-between-jervyn-paller-and-greg-schmidt).